# How can you make preinstall hooks to wait for finishing of the previous hook?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 preinstall scripts that should run sequentially.
They have obviously different weights
The second script must have the first one to finish running.
Is there anyway to make helm support this behavior?

And also for bonus point can you make a pre-install hook to block till the object becomes ready?

**The scenario is as follows:**

You have a database, and an application.

The setup is:

1. create a database (deployment),
2. create a database (service),
3. ran a script that creates all the database users on that db (job)
4. start the application server (deployment).

Comment: Hello @Roman M, did You find the answer?

Comment: basically as explained in detail in the answer below, helm doesn't wait on any objects that are not jobs during the weighted pre-install jobs.                                     So u create a database deployment and service at weight 10.                                  Then u run a hook with weight 11 that exits when pg_ready returns ok answer.             Then on weight 12 u run the job the creates all database users.                        Then the application server deployment object is a regular object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set the [hook weights](https://helm.sh/docs/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook) properly. E.g:

```
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
```

> Hook weights can be positive or negative numbers but must be
>   represented as strings. When Tiller starts the execution cycle of
>   hooks of a particular kind (ex. the `pre-install` hooks or `post-install`
>   hooks, etc.) it will sort those hooks in ascending order.

According to the [Hooks and release lifecycle](https://helm.sh/docs/charts_hooks/#hooks-and-the-release-lifecycle), by default, the Tiller waits until a hook becomes “Ready” before executing the next ones. The catch is: When dealing with scripts managed by hooks, you need to create the resource as a `Job`:

> What does it mean to wait until a hook is ready? This depends on the
>   resource declared in the hook. If the resources is a Job kind, Tiller
>   will wait until the job successfully runs to completion. And if the
>   job fails, the release will fail. **This is a *blocking operation***, so the
>   Helm client will pause while the Job is run.

If you want to run jobs that depend on the database or application to be Ready, it's better to use the hooks as `post-install`, combined with the [`--wait`](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-install-upgrade-rollback) flag. When this flag is set, Tiller will wait until all release resources are deployed and in a ready state and will not run the `post-install` hook until they are ready.

Comment: the first part , you are right about, I put the hook annotation on the wrong metadata, but the second one is still and issue. I need the database to be ready before I run one of the pre-instlal hooks, and one of my release objects. The flow is: create database pod(pre-install), setup users job (pre-install), run app pod (regular install). The probelm is that helm doesn't wait for the readyness check on the database to pass. when the pod is running, it moves to the next preinstalll hook

Comment: If you want the database ready, you need to use a `post-install` (not `pre`). With `--wait` flag it only runs after the release resources are ready

Comment: but post install will run after the app pod is already up? which is too late.